# MailMerge in Access VBA invokes a Select Table popup on a .xls file with only one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-word, mailmerge

This code is supposed to generate labels that will be used for labeling specimens collected during deep water dives.

```vb
Sub MailMergeSpecimenLabels()
    Dim pathMergeTemplates As String
    Dim pathMergeLabels As String
    Dim pathMergeTemp As String
    Dim outfilename As String
    Dim infilename As String
    Dim templatefilename As String
    Dim msg As String
    
    'Get the word template from the templates folder
    
    pathMergeTemplates = CurrentProject.Path & "\templates\"
    pathMergeLabels = CurrentProject.Path & "\completed\"
    pathMergeTemp = CurrentProject.Path & "\temp\"
            
    'Export the data using a Macro
    
    templatefilename = pathMergeTemplates & "Primary_Specimens.docx"
    infilename = pathMergeTemp & "SpecimenLabels.xls"
    outfilename = pathMergeLabels & "PrimarySpecLabels_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddmms") & ".docx"
            
    DoCmd.RunMacro ("ExportPrimarySpecsforLabels")
    
    ' Access has built the .xls file.
    'Now the mail merge doc gets opened
    
        Dim appWord As Object
        Dim docWord As Object
        
        Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    'Open the template in the templates folder
    
        Set docWord = appWord.Documents.Add(templatefilename, Visible:=False)
        
    'Now we can mail merge without involving the database

        With docWord.MailMerge
            .OpenDataSource Name:=infilename, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False
            .Destination = 0
            .Execute Pause:=False
        End With
        appWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs outfilename
        
        msg = "Specimen Labels are generated.  Would you like to open the label file?"
        DoCmd.RunMacro "MarkPrinted"
        Response = MsgBox(msg, Style)
        If Response = 1 Then
            appWord.Documents.Open filename:=outfilename & "", ReadOnly:=False
        End If
        
        appWord.Quit savechanges:=False
        Set docWord = Nothing
        Set appWord = Nothing
        
Finally:
    Exit Sub
    
Hell:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number, vbExclamation
    
On Error Resume Next
    appWord.Quit savechanges:=False
    Set docWord = Nothing
    Set appWord = Nothing
    Resume Finally
End Sub
```

When the `mailmerge.execute` happens, a popup window (that I can only see if I go to Task Manager) interrupts the code asking me to Select Table. How can I avoid this? There is only one sheet in the .xls file.

I thought I found the problem when I rebuilt the template and got that Select Table popup there when setting my data source, but it did not work.

Comment: Why use Word merge instead of just an Access report? Why export to Excel?

Comment: well, I'm using MailMerge to create the labels that go to a special museum quality printer onboard the ship.  I'm exporting to Excel, because when I try to use mailmerge with an access query, it often doesn't work and gives me an error that the database is locked.  I found online that it would be better to export to excel or text and then call the mail merge, so that is the path that I've been on today.  By the way, I figured out my 2nd issue.  Now just need help with the 1st.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why not use an Access report instead of merge?

Comment: What happens if you specify `docWord.MailMerge.Execute Pause:=False`

Comment: Thank you dbmitch for your suggestion.  I am setting that and it is still happening.  At this point, I am faced with my user having to have task manager open to interact with the Select Table popup and after that it all works.  I have updated my code block in the post.

Answer (score 1):

When running a mailmerge from another application, you need to disable any mailmerge alerts in the document being used for the mailmerge - which kills the mailmerge parameters in that document - then reinstate the mailmerge parameters in code. Hence:

```
Sub MailMergeSpecimenLabels()
' Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model to be set, via Tools|References in the VBE.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, Response As Long
Dim StrMMSrc As String, StrMMDoc As String, StrMMOut As String, StrName As String
Const msg As String = "Specimen Labels are generated.  Would you like to open the label file?"
'Define the files & paths
StrMMDoc = CurrentProject.Path & "\templates\Primary_Specimens.docx"
StrMMSrc = CurrentProject.Path & "\temp\SpecimenLabels.xls"
StrMMOut = CurrentProject.Path & "\completed\PrimarySpecLabels_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddmms") & ".docx"

DoCmd.RunMacro ("ExportPrimarySpecsforLabels")

With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=StrMMDoc, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    With .MailMerge
      .MainDocumentType = wdMailingLabels
      .OpenDataSource Name:=StrMMSrc, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
        "Data Source=StrMMSrc;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`"
      .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
  Set wdDoc = Nothing
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
  
  With .ActiveDocument
    .SaveAs Filename:=StrMMOut, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
    
    DoCmd.RunMacro "MarkPrinted"
    
    Response = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo)
    If Response = vbYes Then
      .Activate
    Else
      .Close SaveChanges:=False
      wdApp.Quit: Set wdApp = Nothing
    End If
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you macropod for this.  You are an answer to a prayer!  I will work on this now and report back.

Comment: Other than the Application.ScreenUpdating throwing an error for some reason, this worked very well.  Thank you very much @macropod!!  The only other thing is that the .Activate is not bringing the Word document up to the front for the user, but I can live with that.  You seriously have saved me!!  I appreciate your help so much.